# MATLAB's color interpolation bug in patch command

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

This is related to my previous question, ([Matlab's patch function with interpolation produces different result based on order of vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58020419/12092999)), where I fixed my code to include the first vertex as the last one to close the patch, and got consistent answers.

Now, as the patch is on a square domain, if I shift the color coordinates, the interpolated patch should be consistent but it is not. I will use the same example:

```
x = [0.9000    1.0000    1.0000  0.9000]';
y = [0.5000    0.5000    0.6000  0.6000]';
c = [0.0278    0.0371    0.0325    0.0282]';
order1 = [1:4,1]; %Edit according to last answer
figure;patch(x(order1),y(order1),c(order1));
order2 = [2:4,1:2];%order shift only for color
figure;patch(x(order1),y(order1),c(order2));
```

The inconsistency is hard to understand. Any explanation or a way around it would be helpful.

Comment: Why should the interpolation be consistent? Interpolation is done in triangles. If you reorder the colors, you get different colors on the two triangle vertices, and hence different interpolation results.

Comment: This makes sense and explains the behavior. I wish the result were bilinear interpolation over the quad for my problem (knowing that the patch command is generic for n vertices). Still, I would like to know some workarounds. Thanks @CrisLuengo